# Exchange 2007 and Droid Rezound SD CARD Encryption

Tags: exchange-2007, encryption, android

We have an Exchange 2007 server that supports many DROIDX phones. The configurations are setup to only enforce a pin code. However on the DROID REZOUND, it forces you to encrypt the SDCARD. This basically breaks a lot of applications it seems that cannot read the storage device. Is this the Android OS doing it or something screwed up on the Exchange server? Storage encryption is not enabled on the server.

Thanks

Comment: Well I am not sure if there some issue in the translation between Exchange and the Android OS, so I deleted my Exchange Account from the device and used Touchdown instead.